# Windows - How to search a word with a number in a fixed position

Tags: windows, windows-search

I'm trying to search inside files for a word and a number in a fixed position.

Example:

> Fast 104

However, the search results will give me any files containing the word "Fast" and "104", regardless of the number being next to the word or not.

What command do I need to use to find only the file with fixed position (using Windows 10 Pro)?

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to install any third-party programs.

Comment: What kind of files, and with what search tool ?

Comment: Have you tried enclosing in double quotes?

Comment: @DrMoishe-Pippik tried various things, "Fast?104" seemed like it should work but it didn't either. Double quotes don't seem to work.

Comment: @harrymc Windows search tool to find specific word with a specific number (street adress with a number) inside excel or word files (libre office to be exact)

Comment: What does "fixed position" mean ?

Comment: @harrymc "fixed position" means that the word and the number have to be next to each other, with the number being on the right side of the word.

Comment: You're not then looking for "Fast 104" but for any word followed by a number?

Comment: @harrymc yes, that is correct. As I said before, the purpose is to find any street adress followed by a number inside word or excel files using windows search tool or any other given tools that come with installing windows.

Comment: Windows search may not be the best tool. Are third-party tools possible? Are all the searched files inside one folder?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, all the searched files are inside one folder. Third party tools only possible if they don't come with using administrator rights to install them. So maybe at best some zip files.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the excellent and free
[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/),
and especially its menu command of *Search > Find in files...*

With this you may search all the files in a directory for
a given regular expression (regex).

To avoid installing software, you could use the version of
[Notepad++ Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/development/notepadpp_portable).

The search string to use would be `\w+\s+\d+`, where:

- `\w+` : Any number of word characters
- `\s+` : Any number of space characters
- `\d+` : Any number of digits.

[image]